# Mysql Wrong Date Format

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

Hi I am trying to convert dd-mm-yy to yy-mm-dd in mysql but I'm getting wrong date as below :

```
 query :  select STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2018','%Y-%m-%d')
   result:  2001-09-20
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Clearly, the third part is Y. Obviously, we can only guess as to which of the other parts is m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below: format string is wrong in your case

```
select STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2018','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Output:

```
'2018-09-01'
```

Comment: yes, it's working but may I know how is it possible since you have specified '%d-%m-%Y' format ?

Comment: it is the string format of '01-09-2018' like in this string it is d then m then Y so in format you've to specify in that order otherwise it will not work

Comment: yes I wll mark it Accepted, Thank You ..

Comment: @KiranKumar I've added an explanation in my answer which explains why you were mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in the right way. It takes a string `str` and a format string `format`. Format pattern has to match your input `str`. In your case, you had **dd-mm-yy** has input, so you have to use matching format, that is, `%d-%m-%Y`

Try the following:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2018','%d-%m-%Y')
```

**Additional Details:**

- **%d**   Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- **%m**   Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- **%Y**   Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
- Note that `STR_TO_DATE` function will always return in MySQL standard date format, which is `yyyy-mm-dd` (if input is date only).
- If you want to convert into some other format, then you will need to use a combination of [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) alongwith [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you're confusing the parameters. In your example you provide `%Y-%m-%d` which is your **expected output**. The second parameter of `STR_TO_DATE` should be the format of the string you're supplying:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2018','%d-%m-%Y')
```

The default MySQL datestring is: `%Y-%m-%d`, which is what is yielded from the query above:

```
2018-09-01
```

See the following SQL fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2411rcvjH6dKZYLzxkii39/0

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wrote the parsing parameters wrong... the should point to the string's parameters

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2018','%d-%m-%Y');
```